# exception thrown "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" what to do?

Tags: c#, .net

This is my code.but value cannot inserted in database. it takes system datetime except selected value by drop down list.

```
 string strDateOfBirth = ddlMonth.SelectedValue.ToString();
 strDateOfBirth = strDateOfBirth + "/" + ddlBirthDate.SelectedValue.ToString();
 strDateOfBirth = strDateOfBirth + "/" + ddlYear.SelectedValue.ToString();

 //objVivah.BirthDate = DateTime.ParseExact(strDateOfBirth, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", null);  
 objVivah.BirthDate = Convert.ToDateTime(strDateOfBirth);
 // objVivah.BirthDate = Convert.ToString(strDateOfBirth);
```

Comment: Please can you indicate the actual value of `strDateOfBirth` after the first 3 lines.

Comment: And please, don't post commented out code that only serves as distraction.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a `String` to a `DateTime` using the `Convert.ToDateTime` function, the `String` must be in a specific format. If your `String` has a different format you need to convert it using [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) function:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(strDateOfBirth, "MM/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
objVivah.BirthDate = DateTime.ParseExact(strDateOfBirth, "MM/dd/yyyy", null);
```

You might want to have a look at TryParse as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I wouldn't create the string to start with - if you already have each part, you can parse *those* as integers (using `int.Parse`) and then create a DateTime from that. Or for the drop-down lists, you may be able to avoid even having the string value to start with, which would be ideal. (Make the *value* associated with each item just an integer. This may not be feasible depending on what UI technology you're using - you haven't said whether it's WinForms, ASP.NET, WPF etc.)

Using `DateTime.ParseExact` with an appropriate format string is the second best way to go, but I don't see any point in creating a string only to then parse it.